# Regex match specific word with dollar sign?

Tags: regex

I have sentences like:

`$COIN has a new price target increase to $400`

I only want to match `$COIN` with regex, I am wondering how to do this?

If I do something like `.*\\$.*` it also matches `$400`. I would just like to match the `$SOMEWORDNOSPACE` only. Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Try with `\\$[A-Z]+\b`

Answer (score 1):

If everything after $ until the end of the word is a capital letter: `\$[A-Z]+`

This will match the $ (`\$`), and then match between 1 and infinity capital letters `[A-Z]+`. The match stops when a character doesn't fit in the A-Z range, so `\b` is unnecessary. If the match can't start in the middle of the sentence you could start with `\B` so it starts matching on a switch of a word character to the dollar sign, in that case the regex would be `\B\$[A-Z]+`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```py
(?<!\S)\$[A-Z]+(?!\S)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/82RaC5/1)

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S                       non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \$                       '$'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Z]+                   any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S                       non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```